# Unable to send JSON via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I made a function which counts how much time I spent on some page and where I came from. I collect all the data and save it into a JSON but when I try to send that JSON via ajax on the success it alerts me with an empty alert box, which means that nothing is being sent. I tried to add async to false because I use the **onbeforeunload** function but that doesn't work. I tried numberless combinations with AJAX setting but nothing is working.

**HTML / JS**

```
(function(){
var time,timeSite,endTime,seconds,testObject,retrievedObject,text;
window.onload=function(){
    time= new Date();       
}
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
    endTime = new Date();
    timeSite= time.getTime()-endTime.getTime();
    seconds =Math.abs(timeSite/1000);
    window.localStorage['seconds']=seconds;
    text = 'Visitor accessed site directly.';
    if(document.referrer == ''){
        var link = text;
    } else{
        var link = document.referrer;
    } 
     var url = window.location.href;
     var main = {
        'From': link,
        'Current was' : url,
        'Time Spent': seconds
     }
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: {'data': main},
           url: "http://localhost:8080/projectFour/test.php", //i use this page only to check if i receive data
           contentType:'application/json',
           success:  function(data) {
                alert(data);
           }, 
           error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {

            alert(ajaxOptions);
        }
        else {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }
       });
}
})();
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['main'])) { 
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['main']); 
    //some php operation 
    echo $obj; 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: need to stringify the object yourself

Comment: I already tried, that doesn't work...

Comment: the comment next to the url...is confusing.. maybe your understand of the url prop is incorrect.

Comment: Just an aside: `if (xhr.status == 200) {

            alert(ajaxOptions);
        }` in the error block will never execute. The error function will only run if the status != 200 (i.e. status is not "OK", i.e. an error). When the HTTP status is 200 the "success" function will execute.

Comment: Anyway, alerting with an empty box in the "success" function doesn't prove nothing was sent, unless `test.php` is just programmed to directly return what was posted without changing it. What does the code of `test.php` look like?

Comment: test.php containes: 
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['main'])){
  $obj = json_decode($_POST['main']);
  //some php operation
  echo $obj;
 }
 ?>

Comment: There is your problem, the variable that you are sending is 'data' not 'main'.

Comment: Again, nothing is happening. When i reload test.php page that page is blank...

Comment: making an asynchronous request at unbeforeunload is not guaranteed to make it to the server

Comment: when you set contentType as json $_POST will be empty and you can't use blocking code like `alert()` within unload events

Answer (score 1):

Your test.php is looking for a POST variable called `main`, but you're sending one called `data`.

You can change the data part of the ajax call from:

```
data: {'data': main}
```

to

```
data: {'main': main}
```

and that should cause it to post the variable with `main` as the variable name.

Secondly, when you return the data, it would be better to return it as JSON again, otherwise it might mangle the result a bit.

Replace

```
echo $obj;
```

with

```
echo json_encode($obj);
```

And in the ajax replace

```
alert(data);
```

with

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

That will give you a view of the returned data structure as a string.

You should also consider returning something from PHP when the `if` statement is false, whether that be an error code, or some other response. Sending no response in this case isn't very helpful to the client side, and has hindered your debugging.